# How to pass custom directive name dynamically in class attribute of div tag?

Tags: angularjs

I am very new to AngularJS. I have made a custom directive `user` and I want to call it dynamically in class attribute by using a variable.
e.g. `$scope.dirName = "user";`
When i use this variable in below code:

```
<div class = {{dirName}}></div>
```

Its result must show two input fields with specified values. But it is not doing so. When I replace `{{dirName}}` with `user`. It is working fine, means two input fields are shown with values as specified. Can anybody tell, what mistake I am doing?

This is index.html

```
<div ng-controller = "Ctrl">
<form name = "myForm">
  <div class = {{dirName}}></div>
  <hr>
  <tt>userName : {{user}}</tt>
</form>
```

This is script.js

```
<pre>var app = angular.module('App',[]);

app.controller('Ctrl', function($scope){
 $scope.user = {name:'adya',last:'Rajput'};
 $scope.dirName = "user";
});

app.directive('user',function(){
 return{
   restrict:'C',
   templateUrl:'template.html'
 };
});</pre>
```

template.html contains:

```
UserName : <input type='text' name='userName' ng-model='user.name' required>
LastName : <input type='text' name='lastName' ng-model='user.last'>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, you cannot save names of directives in string variables and access them in the HTML. You can, however, save a string in a variable in `$scope` and [use `ng-switch`](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3angSwitch) to *select* the correct directive:

```html
<div ng-switch="dirName">
    <div ng-switch-when="ng-user">
      <div ng-user></div>
    </div>

    <div ng-switch-when="...">
      ...
    </div>
</div>
```

However, now it might be better to use something more descriptive than `ng-user` to *switch* over.

**Sidenote:** Do not use *ng-* prefix in your own directives. Angular uses that prefix so that it does not collide with other namespaces. You should use your own prefix for your directives.

---

**Update**: For the updated question as to why `<div class="{{dirName}}"></div>` does not work, it happens because angular [`$compile`s the directive](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24compile) only once. If you first [`$interpolate`](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24interpolate) the content of the template (which will replace `{{dirName}}` with `ng-user`) and then explicitly `$compile` it before entering it in the HTML, it should work.

Comment: ok Fixing that in my question.
"Unfortunately, you cannot save names of directives in string variables and access them in the HTML". Can you please tell me why this is not possible. Because when i have checked console for HTML, it is getting value of dirName but it is not getting the result.
I mean i am getting this `<div class="ng-user"></div>` in console but it is not displaying two input fields with specified value.

Comment: That is an interesting question. This happens because angular [`$compile`s the directive](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$compile) only once. If you first [`$interpolate`](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$interpolate) the content of the template and then explicitly `$compile` it, it should work.