# Add a directive to an element with AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs, events, directive

I've been playing with AngularJS for a few days but I still can't grasp some things about the way directives are managed, and I could not find any good answer anywhere for what I'm looking for.

Let's say I have a specific div in which I want to add a directive on a specific event, e.g. on a click. What is the best way to do so ? Or is my approach totally wrong, and should this be done in another way ?

I've set up a Plunker to better illustrate my problem : http://plnkr.co/edit/KM2KFVb6iuhtQKrLYax1?p=preview

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This question partly explains why your method doesn't work: [How to pass custom directive name dynamically in class attribute of div tag?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20052751/how-to-pass-custom-directive-name-dynamically-in-class-attribute-of-div-tag/20052968#20052968)

Also, that is not the *angular*-esque way of doing things. I suspect this would be more *angular* like while doing what you want: http://plnkr.co/edit/fNZvZ1vzQYQLjZti37GQ?p=preview

**Template**

```
<div class="whatever" ng-if="!directiveOn">div.whatever</div>
<div newstuff ng-if="directiveOn">div.whatever</div>
```

**Controller**

```js
  $scope.directiveOn = false;
  $scope.click = function() {
    $scope.directiveOn = true;
  };
```

The other option would be to *pass* the directive the information of whether it is *turned on* or *off*.

Comment: Thank you so much! This is exactly the solution I was looking for. It makes perfect sense from an Angular point of view.