# Variable named directive angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am looking to find a way to implement variable directives:

```
.constant('BLADES', [
        {
            "name":"static",
            "order":1,
            "image": "img/blade_images/widgets-01.png"
        },
        {
            "name":"static",
            "order":2,
            "image": "img/blade_images/widgets-01.png"
        },
        {
            "name":"static",
            "order":3,
            "image": "img/blade_images/widgets-01.png"
        }
    ])
```

Using the above constant populated from server data I would like to define the directives to load on the page

```
<div ng-repeat="blade in blades">
    <{{name}}-directive image="{{image}}">
    </{{name}}-directive>   
</div>
```

However the above does not work, does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: I don't think that's possible; see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20052751/how-to-pass-custom-directive-name-dynamically-in-class-attribute-of-div-tag) for a similar problem.

Comment: while having dynamic directive name is not possible, but you can get away with this limitation by writing a wrapper directive, which will add the dynamically named directive to DOM.

Comment: Thanks @harish A wrapper directive? This sounds interesting, do you know of or can think of an approach example i might use to build this wrapper directive?

Answer (score 0):

What you're trying to do is impossible ([see documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/compiler)). Directive names have to be already resolved at the beginning of the compilation. Interpolation of `{{bindings}}` is done as part of the compilation process - after all the template code has already been read and parsed for directive names, etc.

To reach your goal, you'd need to pre-process your template with [some other tool](https://lodash.com/docs#template) first and let it be compiled by AngularJS only when it contains the resolved directives.

Answer (score 0):

as per discussion in comment i am giving you a very raw example of a wrapper directive, which you will have to work over to make it usable.

wrapper directive

```
    <wrapper item="selected"></wrapper>
```

and then in wrapper

```
.directive('wraper', function ($compile) {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
            item: "="
        },
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            var directive = item + '-directive';
            var html = '<' + directive + '></' +  directive + '>';
            var e =$compile(html)(scope);
            element.replaceWith(e);
        }
    };
});
```

Comment: did the answer helped?