# Loading directive (dynamic templateUrls) in ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat

[Plunker Demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/kiP5lNTMLQyRdayKGVnK?p=preview)

I created two custom directives for template usage in a `ng-repeater`.

Outside of the ng-repeater, the directives work. Once I try to dynamically load the directives in a `ng-repeater`, the directives do not load at all. In fact - when use "Inspect Element" - the `{{expressions}}` do not dynamically update.

Here is how my ng-repeater looks:

```
<div ng-repeat="section in content">
  <section class="section-{{ section.block }}" block="{{ section.block }}">{{ section.block }}</section>
</div>
```

I am calling the directives via `restrict: C`

Here is one of the directives:

```
.directive('sectionHeader', function() {
    return {
      restrict: 'EAC',
      scope: {
        block: '='
      },
      templateUrl: 'sectionHeader.html'
    };
  })
```

Here is the templateURL:

```
<div class="container">
    <figure class="icon">
        <img class="img-fluid" ng-src="{{ block.icon }}" title="App Icon">
    </figure>
    <h1>{{ block.title }}</h1>
    <figure class="hero">
        <img class="img-fluid" ng-src="{{ block.image }}" title="App">
    </figure>
</div>
```

And a snippet of the JSON:

```
$scope.content = [
      {
        block: 'header',
        icon: 'http://www.placehold.it/128x128?text=PLACEHOLpng',
        title: 'Header Title',
        image: 'http://www.placehold.it/1200x675?text=PLACEHOLDER'
      },...
];
```

Now, I believe The templateUrls are not loading because it seems like the directives are being executed before ng-repeat get its content. What I believe I need to do is to execute the directives after ng-repeat receives the content. I am not sure where to start.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve that using [$compile](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile) function.

See example on  [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/zbWQOXRny2phVT9SplKj?p=preview).

#### Create general directive with `$compile`.

```
.directive('section', function($compile) {
return {
  restrict: 'EAC',
  scope: {
    block: '='
  },
  link:function(scope,elem){
    if(scope.block)
      $compile(elem.html('<section-'+scope.block.block+' block="block">'))(scope);
  }
};
})
```

#### Create two different directive.

```
 .directive('sectionHeader', function() {
return {
  restrict: 'EAC',
  scope: true,
  templateUrl: 'sectionHeader.html'
};
})

.directive('sectionHundred', function() {
return {
  restrict: 'EAC',
  scope: true,
  templateUrl: 'sectionHundred.html'
};
});
```

#### And usage

```
<div ng-repeat="section in content">
  <section  block="section"></section>
</div>
```

#### JSON data:

```
 [
  {
    block: 'header',
    icon: 'http://www.placehold.it/128x128?text=PLACEHOLpng',
    title: 'Header Title',
    image: 'http://www.placehold.it/1200x675?text=PLACEHOLDER'
  },
  {
    block: 'hundred',
    icon: 'http://www.placehold.it/128x128?text=PLACEHOLpg',
    title: 'Hundred Title',
    content: 'Hundred Content',
    link: {
      copy: 'Link Copy',
      title: 'Link Title',
      url: '#'
    },
    image: 'http://www.placehold.it/1200x675?text=PLACEHOLDER'
  }
];
```

Comment: Thanks. That did the trick. It was even only an addition of 10 lines to the JS. Any benefit of using `directive`s in a `ng-repeat` to build dynamic templates vs using `ng-include`s? Literally last night read that `ng-include`s to build out templates in an `ng-repeat` hurts performance of web speeds.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use directive by passing their name dynamically.

But a possible workaround is to use ng-switch instead :

```
<div ng-repeat="section in content">
<div ng-switch="section.block">
    <section ng-switch-when="header" class="section-header" block="{{ section.block }}">{{ section.block }}</section>
    ... another ng-switch...
</div>
```

See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20052751/how-to-pass-custom-directive-name-dynamically-in-class-attribute-of-div-tag) for more details

Comment: Link-only posts are not encouraged on StackOverflow. Could you please include the essential parts of your link in your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Though @stepan-kasyanenko gave me a correct answer - I further removed extra lines of code not needed to minimize the build.

New [Plunker Link](https://plnkr.co/edit/oRbKi27e1Vc8npPVAgmo?p=preview) with answer added.

**home.html**

Old:

```
<div ng-repeat="section in content">
   <section  block="section"></section>
</div>
```

New:

```
<section ng-repeat="section in content" block="section"></section>
```

I placed the `ng-repeat` in the `<section>` that calls the `directive`

**directives**

```
.directive('sectionHeader', function() {
    return {
      restrict: 'EAC',
      replace: true,
      scope: true,
      templateUrl: 'sectionHeader.html'
    };
  });
```

I added `replace: true,` to both `directive`s because the `ng-repeat` builds out another `<section>` inside of the `<section ng-repeat>` element

Thank you @stepan-kasyanenko